# Word VBA: Access the "Runs" of the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

The open XML standard defines "runs" that are essentially strings of text that make up a paragraph (if I understand them correctly). I'm curious if anyone knows a way to access the document at the "run" level rather then the paragraph level. For instance:

```
dim tRun as Run

for each tRun in Activedocument.Runs
    'Some code
next tRun
```

Obviously, the above does not work. Is this possible through VBA?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of "runs". But as you mention the XML standard, I assume by runs you mean the summary of all "subpieces" in a paragraph that e.g. may have a special formatting. To clarify this idea:

```
<p>And so quote the raven: <italic>Nevermore!</italic></p>
```

So in this example, "And so quote the raven: " and "Nevermore!" would be two runs.

However, the Word object model embraces many collections. `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs` is just one. There are also:

- `ActiveDocument.Characters`
- `ActiveDocument.Words`
- `ActiveDocument.Sentences`
- `ActiveDocument.Fields`

etc. By this collections, you can pick any smaller text pieces. But to address these pieces, you don't have to go through a paragraph.

One thing all those smaller text pieces have in common is the `Range` property. You can inspect the Range of any piece, it'll have a `Start` and `End` number. Those are non-ambiguously the numbers of the characters in the document which you can count directly. And further, the `Range` has a `Font` property. In this `Font` property, all the information is stored that would fit to the initially definition for "run".

A further, more dynamic approach to get text pieces is to use `ActiveDocuments.Range(start, end)`. By this, you'll get a `Range` Object that has again all the collections mentioned above: characters, words, paragraphs, sentences etc. The range's collections contain only the items that actually lie within the range, in contrast to the document's collections.

To sum it up: In a word document, you have no runs but you have several sophisticated collections. The collections are connected by a non-ambiguous start and end range number. So you can find from the paragraph to its words or from a sentence to the embracing paragraph etc.

For a further understanding, you might want to read about the Word object model at MSDN, or just inspect the model in a Word document in the VBA editor in the watch window.

Comment: This is the right concept but I think you might want to read up on the OpenXML standard. This is the "x" in '.docx." Thin in terms of HTML where you have a paragraph <p> and font tag. The paragraph can contain many different font tags  describing chunks of text. A run would be like one of these font tags. the XML tag for a run is <w:r> and it is inside of a <w:p> tag. The <w:r> tag has <w:rpr> and <w:t> child tags (run properties and text respectively). A <w:p> tag can contain several <w:r> tags in the same manner as the <p> and <font> tags in the HTML example I provided.

Comment: There is quiet a difference between the object structure of a Word document as it is in memory, and accessable through VBA, and its representation as docx. Your question was asking for a way to parse smaller units than paragraphs with VBA. Therefore my answer focuses on the VBA collections. Once you inspect a word paragraph with the VBA editor, you will see that each character has its font information, and more. For parsing a docx XML, you'll need other tools.

Comment: I understand. My questions was much more specific that you assumed. I'm looking for something like a collection of runs. It seems that's just not possible.